# Subset fields from an ordereddict?

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

So, I have an ordered dictionary, and its has a pile of key/value pairs. I can extract ALL them with the items() method. But what if I only want to select SOME of them ?

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.OrderedDict({'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 1,'orange': 2})
>>> d.items()
[('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)]
```

What if I just want apple and banana ?

Is there a way I can specify the keys I want ?

```
>>> d['apple','banana'] <-- does not work
```

I was considering using a list comprehension at the end to filter the results, but seems messy and I hope there is a better way.

Comment: What would you like `d['apple','banana']` to produce?

Comment: A list of tuples or key/value pairs, same as .items() does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll most likely wind up using a list comprehension one way or another. Here is a way to bury the list comprehension in a method implementation:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class MultOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def items(self, *items):
        all = super(MultOrderedDict, self).items()
        if not items:
            return all
        return type(self)((key, value) for (key, value) in all if key in items).items()
```

With that class definition (assuming it's in `multorddict.py`) you can do something like this:

```
>>> from multorddict import MultOrderedDict
>>> mod = MultOrderedDict(banana=3, apple=4, pear=1, orange=2)
>>> mod.items()
[('orange', 2), ('pear', 1), ('apple', 4), ('banana', 3)]
>>> mod.items('apple','banana')
[('apple', 4), ('banana', 3)]
>>>
```

This approach changes the semantics of the `items` method, which might not be such a good thing.

Comment: This doesn't return a list of tuples or key/value pairs, same as `items()` does. It also infinitely recurses when `mod['apple', 'banana']` is executed.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't test my initial implementation in python2 (it doesn't have the same problem in python3). I would just delete the answer had it not been accepted, but I reworded it to override `items` rather than `__getitem__`. Ultimately it makes more sense to get comfortable with list comprehensions and use those directly.

Answer (score 5):

You could define a one-liner to do it:

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.OrderedDict({'banana': 3, 'apple': 4, 'pear': 1,'orange': 2})
>>> d.items()
[('orange', 2), ('pear', 1), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)]
>>>
>>> subset = lambda d, *keys: [(key, d[key]) for key in keys]
>>> subset(d, 'apple', 'banana')
[('apple', 4), ('banana', 3)]
```

As a bonus it also works with regular `dict` objects.

**Update**

To get a resulting list in the same order as the `OrderedDict`, as @Maxim Veksler seems to think you might want, the ordered dictionary would have to be defined in a way that gave it specific order. In Python versions before 3.6 that have to be done something like this instead of what you have in your question:

```
d = collections.OrderedDict([('banana', 3), ('apple', 4), ('pear', 1), ('orange', 2)])
```

Which passes a `list` argument to the constructor instead of one that's a regular `dict`.

So assuming that's done (or not if you're using Python 3.6+), you could define the `subset()` function like this:

```
subset = lambda d, *keys: [(key, d[key]) for key in d.keys() if key in set(keys)]
```

Which would return this result given a correctly created sample `OrderedDict` input:

```
>>> subset(d, 'apple', 'banana')
[('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)]
```

Note that pairs in the list returned are now in the same order as the key are in the `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Wouldn't it lose the order of the keys that OrderedDict is meant to preserve ?

Comment: @Maxim: The OP said nothing in the question about the result maintaining the order of the original `Orderedict`. Check out their response to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40335561/subset-fields-from-an-ordereddict#comment67926514_40335561) I asked in a comment regarding what they result wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a method that exists but it might be worth while to create a generic method if this is something you find yourself having to do through out your code base. Maybe something like

```
>>> specific_dict_items = lambda d, l: [(key, d.get(key, '')) for key in l]
>>> specific_dict_items({1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5}, [1, 3, 5, 7])
[(1, 1), (3, 3), (5, 5), (7, '')]
```